# Why was @Moshe suspended? Can this be reconsidered?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, suspension

New user @Moshe has only contributed 4 answers and no questions; and those answers don't show signs of suspension-worthy activity. [One of these answers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/68118/7643), which is quite informative and useful IMHO, albeit being, shall we see, very strongly worded in a few places, made me wonder whether it, in itself, was the cause.

That would be unfortunate, since the perspective of a user with intimate knowledge of the situation in Afghanistan would be quite helpful these days.

I ask the moderators to consider un-suspending @Moshe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can not publicly discuss suspensions of users.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, but for privacy reasons we can not publicly discuss suspensions of specific users. Suspensions are a matter between the suspended user, the moderators and the community team if either party chooses to escalate the matter to them.

Keep in mind that we moderators usually *remove* offensive content. So if you look only at the publicly visible contributions of a suspended user and find nothing suspension-worthy, then we did our job correctly.

Comment: Ah, that twisted logic again from the Monica Cellio affair. No, my friend, sanctions must be publicly justifiable - in our case, to the community. If privacy prevents you from giving justification, it must also prevent you from sanctioning. Secret trials and punishments are immoral and oppressive.

Comment: @einpoklum If you want to debate why we are handling suspensions that way, then please post it as a new question with no relation to any specific case.

Comment: @einpoklum This is how moderation has worked for the entire history of Stack Exchange, including the part where we respect confidentiality of the suspended individual. It is not new. Not airing anybody's dirty laundry publicly is seen as crucial to giving suspended individuals a chance to re-integrate whenever they're ready to return after their suspension ends.

Comment: @doppelgreener: 1. It was problematic from the get-go; but in recent years things seem to have worsened. 2. You don't "respect confidentiality", you invent it. Only in repressive regimes are verdicts, sentences and punishments kept confidential. 3. "chance to re-integrate" - unless you prove otherwise to the public, those people can only reasonably be assumed not to have done anything wrong.

Comment: Again, if you want to debate this policy, open a new question. Further comments here will be deleted.

Comment: Is the criteria for suspension in general known to non moderators and non staff? I am not talking about the person mentioned here.

Comment: @Gary2 You can find that information on the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help). Particularly in the article about [expected behavior](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) which also links to the [code of conduct](https://politics.stackexchange.com/conduct). If you have further questions, please open a new question.